# Determine values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ for normally distributed random variable $X$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

$X$ is a normally distributed (N($\mu$,$\sigma^2$)) random variable with $\mathbb{P}(X\leq0)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X\leq1)=\frac{2}{3}$. Determine values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

I've tried solving 
$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}dx = \frac{1}{3}$$ and 
$$\int_{-\infty}^1\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}dx = \frac{2}{3}$$
simultaneously for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ but that didn't seem to work. Any idea on how to solve this problem? Do I need to use the central limit theorem?

**Update**

So I can say that if $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ then
$$\mathbb{P}(Z\leq \frac{-\mu}{\sigma}) = \frac{1}{3} = P(Z>1-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})$$
For the first part of the equation we have a negative value $-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$
So we rewrite this as $$\mathbb{P}(Z\leq \frac{-\mu}{\sigma}) = \mathbb{P}(Z> \frac{\mu}{\sigma}) = 1- \mathbb{P}(Z\leq \frac{\mu}{\sigma})$$

And therefore in the normal table: 1 - $\Phi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}) = \frac{1}{3}$ and 1 - $\Phi(1-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})= \frac{1}{3}$. However, if I look up the values in the table I find that these equations seem to contradict each other. Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: Hint: Transform to Z-score (standard score)

Comment: To be slightly more explicit then @yongkai, recall that $z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ and use this to create a simpler algebraic system of equations.

Comment: by symmetry, $\mu=0.5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** you have: $$\mathsf P(X\leqslant 0)~=~\tfrac 1 {~3~}~=~\mathsf P(X> 1)$$

Or, if $Z:=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, so that $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$

$$\mathsf P(Z\leqslant \frac{-\mu}{\sigma})~=~\tfrac 1 {~3~}~=~\mathsf P(Z> \frac{1-\mu}{\sigma})$$

Comment: Shouldn't the last equation read $P(Z>\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma})$?

Comment: Indeed, it xhould

Comment: I've edited my calculations but still seem to make a mistake

Comment: @Whizkid95 $1-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \neq \frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}$